# OSX Audio: use Garage Band Plug-ins in my own app

Tags: macos, plugins, audio, logic

I'm writing a little app for the Mac, that involves recording a voice.
In GarageBand, and in Logic for that matter, there is a plug-in called Speech Enhancer.
Is there any way I can piggyback on this plug-in, offering those users that have GB or Logic installed the comfort of noise cancellation and equalizing the built-in mike of their Mac?
The plug-in doesn't show up in the AULab, so I expect it to be an exclusive Apple-thingy (which is outrageous by the way).
Any suggestions?
Thanks
Sjakelien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AudioUnit plugins in both Garage Band and Logic are exclusive to those programs and can't be used in other hosts, as you had suspected.  However, there are plenty of great third-party plugins out there which you could use to achieve the same effect... just do a search over at the [KVR Audio plugin database](http://www.kvraudio.com/get.php).  You might be able to find a nice freeware plugin that does what you want, or you could possibly cut a deal with a developer to redistribute a plugin with your app.

Also, you should keep in mind that while there are plenty of vocal processing plugins out there, you can also brew your own with an effect chain built from several other effects.  For instance, you can generally get pretty good results by chaining up a noise reducer, EQ, stereo enhancer, reverb, and compressor.  There are some more suggestions in [this nice harmony central article](http://www.harmony-central.com/articles/tips/13_vocal_processing_tips/), or just google for "studio vocal processing" (or some variation thereof).

Comment: Dear Nik,
thank you for your helpful answer. I'm very lazy, so if I could just re-use Apple's work, that would have been the best.

Comment: Since third parties can develop those plugins, it's certainly possible to use them in third-party applications. The interface etc. is all documented.

Comment: @KubaOber while that is normally true of AU plugins, the garage band ones are exclusive to GB and Logic and will refuse to open in other hosts. This can be easily verified by Ableton Live, which doesn't see or open these plugins. That's specifically what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The AudioUnit interface is part of the Core Audio framework. There is an AudioUnit host application example in the Developer CoreAudio examples folder.